# How to force a derived classes member variable to be a derived type of its parents member variable?

Tags: c++, c++11

Consider the following:

```
#include<string>
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>

struct Storage{
    int baseData{};
};
struct DerivedStorage : Storage{
    int derivedData{};
};

template<typename DS>
class Base{
public:
    Storage* _storage;

    virtual void createStorage(){
        delete _storage;
        _storage = new Storage();
    }

    DS* getStorage(){
        return static_cast<DS*>(_storage);
    }

    void exampleUseOfBaseStorage(){
        _storage->baseData++; //some complex calculation
    }
};

class Derived: Base<DerivedStorage>{
public:

    virtual void createStorage() override{
        delete _storage;
        _storage = new DerivedStorage();
    }

    void exampleUseOfDerivedStorage(){
        getStorage()->derivedData++; //some complex calculation
        std::cout << "derivedData: " << getStorage()->derivedData << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(){
    Derived d;
    d.createStorage();
    d.exampleUseOfDerivedStorage();
    
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is if there is are derived classes from Derived that use a Storage class that does not derive from DerivedStorage:

Eg:

```
struct DerivedStorage2 : Storage{
    int derivedData2{};
};

class Derived2 : public Derived{
public: 
    virtual void createStorage(){
        _storage = new DerivedStorage2(); //Problem here
    }

}
```

getStorage() cast will be incorrect since DerivedStorage2 does not inherit from DerivedStorage.

How to solve this design problem? Using composition (including a different form of storage in each derived class), becomes unwieldy once there are multiple levels of inheritance since each level would add a derived class.

Does this mean that each derived class should also use a template, to avoid derived classes of derived classes using a form of storage that is not derived from the immediate parents storage class ?

Comment: Seems like changing the implementation of `Base::createStorage()` to `delete _storage;        _storage = new DS();` would relieve subclasses of the need to override that method in the first place.   (you could probably replace `Storage * _storage;` with `DS * _storage;` while you're at it, and that would remove the need to `static_cast` when accessing `_storage` later on)

Comment: Is it strictly necessary to have a separate class-tree of `Storage` objects, or could the data just live directly in the `Base`/`Derived` classes as member-variables?

Comment: Okay, you could make your Derived class templated also, e.g. `template<typename DS=DerivedStorage> class Derived: Base<DS> {...}`, so that subclasses could specify their own storage-type as necessary.

Comment: I think if a subclass-implementer did that, he would get compile-time errors from the code in `Derived` that calls the `DerivedStorage` methods, and would (hopefully) realize his mistake and correct it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242614/discussion-between-jeremy-friesner-and-rahul-iyer).

Comment: Please post the solution as an answer.

Comment: @RaymondChen I will leave it for Jeremy to post so he gets points. If he doesn’t post after a few days I will post mine.